# Apache POI MissingCellPolicy is not really working as described in the documentation

Tags: java, excel, apache, automation, apache-poi

I'm trying to set up the Apache POI for a Data Driven automation framework in Java. However, I'm kind of stuck, after several searches at the `setCellData` method.

When I try to check if a Cell in blank, the `getCell` throws this error:

```
The method getCell(int, Row.MissingCellPolicy) in the type XSSFRow is
not applicable for the arguments (int, Class<Row>)
```

And `Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL` is not really accepted:

```
RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell Cell;
    private static XSSFRow Row;

    public static void setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

        try {
            Row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
            Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (Cell == null) {
                Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);
                Cell.setCellValue(Result);
            } else {
                Cell.setCellValue(Result);
            }
```

It does continue afterwards, but I'm interested in the 'try' part.

Thanks a lot,
Cristian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `Row` is a `XSSFRow` which does not contain the enum field `RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL`.

You need to import `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` and then use `Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL`.

I suggest you to rename your variable `Row` to avoid any conflict.

Comment: Oh! There was indeed a conflict with the naming. I changed it to                            xCell = xRow.getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);                                        Thanks a lot kind sir!

Answer (score 9):

Add an import

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy;
```

create a variable

```
private static MissingCellPolicy xRow;
```

and apply as below

```
Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, xRow.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

and if you are still find the issue with the missing policy
 as unexpected type, 
required class or package,
 found variable

Then use this line :
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL